# How to get .getMonth display names of months and not just numbers

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get this .getMonth to display the names of the Months in the cells rather than the number for the month. Super noob so not sure how to get it to do that. So noob I tried .getMonthName. Obviously didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your script in your question as the text instead of the image?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Utilities.formatDate`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `headers[0][1]` and `headers[0][2]` are [Dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), you can use [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to retrieve the month name:

```
const monthName = headers[0][1].toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
```

Or an GAS-specific alternative, using [formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)):

```
const monthName = Utilities.formatDate(headers[0][1], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMMM");
```

#### Reference:

- [Intl.DateTimeFormat() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)
- [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice... I'm not sure how to go about inputting what you gave me. I am a noob. So I have no idea how where to put what you've given me. Headers [0][1] and [0][2] are two cells on a Spreadsheet that have a calendar in them so that if I just imput sept2020 into the HTML with ?=  ?  it gives me the entire date along with the timezone. I've figured out how to get it to recognize the month out of those dates but again they just show up as the number. I'm trying to figure out how to get them to change to the name of the month but again I'm super new to this. Have no clue.

Comment: @AnaMaríaParras `headers[0][1]` and `headers[0][2]` are supposed to be dates, since you're using `getMonth` on them. Are they not? If that's the case, then if you use any of the alternatives I provided, `monthName` is the name of the month related to the input name (e.g. "October"). I thought that's what you wanted to do, but I don't really understand what you're saying now (e.g. `Headers [0][1] and [0][2] are two cells on a Spreadsheet that have a calendar in them`, what does this mean?).

Comment: @AnaMaríaParras I think the issue could be much clarified if you could share a copy of the spreadsheet you're working on, or at least provide the code you're using, not a screenshot (don't attach sensitive information).